# Unable to start Mysql with SELinux

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, selinux

I am attempting to start MySQL with SELinux on CentOS 6 however I am getting the following error.

```
131212 09:08:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
131212 09:08:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /u/mysql
131212  9:08:58 [Warning] Can't create test file /u/mysql/webserver.lower-test
131212  9:08:58 [Warning] Can't create test file /u/mysql/webserver.lower-test
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/u/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
131212  9:08:58 [ERROR] Aborting
```

We have setup MySQL with many other servers however the difference here is that the mysql datadir is in a different partition than the standard /vat/lib.mysql. Instead it is in /u/mysql.

Here is the /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/u/mysql
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

max_allowed_packet = 32M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Here are the permissions for the mysql dir

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql    mysql    system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

and here are the permissions for one of the directorys in the /u/mysql dir

```
drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 databasefolder
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I can confirm that turning SELinux off resolves the issue so it has to be some sort of SELinux permissions issue.

Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My colleague advised that this resolved the issue in the end.

You can see human-readable reasons for denials with

```
audit2why -a
```

To generate new policy modules use

```
audit2allow -a -M <policyname>
```

If you get not found errors

```
yum install policycoreutils-python pschaff
```

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8935

Comment: Without seeing the actual generated policy, it's impossible to determine if this "solution" will cause more problems than it actually solves.

Comment: All I know is that my colleague used this forum post as the solution and it worked for him. We did try the other answer but it did not work for us.

Answer (score 13):

The place to start is to look at your /var/log/audit/audit.log for AVC denied messages relating to mysqld. These can be passed to [audit2why](http://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why) to gather more information to help you decide what to do.

You have your mysql files in a non standard location and although the directories have the correct context it's likely that the files in them are not. The best way to achieve this is to add a new fcontext for the /u/mysql directory

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/u/mysql(/.*)?"
restorecon -rv /u/mysql
```

The [semanage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage) command configures the policy so that subsequent [restorecon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon) commands will not set the context back to the system default.